# Compute co-occurrence matrix by counting values in cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,0,0], 'b': [0,1,1,0], 'c': [0,0,1,1]})
```

I want to get

```
  a b c
a 2 1 0
b 1 2 1
c 0 1 2
```

where a,b,c are column names, and I get the values counting '1' in all columns when the filter is '1' in another column.
For ample, when df.a == 1, we count a = 2, b =1, c = 0 etc

I made a loop to solve

```
matrix = []
for name, values in df.iteritems():
    matrix.append(pd.DataFrame( df.groupby(name, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x == 1].count())).values.tolist()[1])
pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```

But I think that there is a simpler solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You appear to want the matrix product, so leverage `DataFrame.dot`:

```
df.T.dot(df)
   a  b  c
a  2  1  0
b  1  2  1
c  0  1  2
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the same level of performance without the overhead of pandas, you could compute the product with `np.dot`:

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(v.T.dot(v), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

Or, if you want to get cute,

```
(lambda a, c: pd.DataFrame(a.T.dot(a), c, c))(df.values, df.columns)
```

```
   a  b  c
a  2  1  0
b  1  2  1
c  0  1  2
```

[—piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279402/how-to-make-item-item-matrix-with-counting-values-in-cells/50279412?noredirect=1#comment87576012_50279412)

Comment: `(lambda a, c: pd.DataFrame(a.T.dot(a), c, c))(df.values, df.columns)`

Comment: @piRSquared Wow, I'm stealing, er, borrowing that.

Answer (score 11):

### `np.einsum`

Not as pretty as `df.T.dot(df)` but how often do you see `np.einsum` amirite?

```
pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', df, df), df.columns, df.columns)

   a  b  c
a  2  1  0
b  1  2  1
c  0  1  2
```

Comment: Love it, einsum is a difficult beast to tame.

Answer (score 7):

You can do a multiplication using `@` operator for numpy arrays.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T @ df.values, df.columns, df.columns)
```

Comment: Nice, I like this too. Pity it only works for 3.5+ though! (brb, I've reached my daily vote limit...)

Answer (score 4):

Numpy `matmul`

```
np.matmul(df.values.T,df.values)
Out[87]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)

#pd.DataFrame(np.matmul(df.values.T,df.values), df.columns, df.columns)
```

Comment: `df.values.T @ df.values` or `(lambda a: a.T @ a)(df.values)`

Comment: @RafaelC yep , and this is very similar with cold's answer :-)

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote ? Is my solution have something wrong ?